# Perl Mechanize follow_link is failing

Tags: perl, automation, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to login to a site using following code

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(autosave=>1);
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($url);
$mech->follow_link( text => 'Sign In');
$mech->click();
$mech->field(UserName => "$username");
$mech->field(Password => "$password");
$mech->submit();
```

But during follow_link the href contains two front slashes e.g (`//test/sso-login`) hence follow_link is considering it as whole URL and it's failing as below

```
Error GETing http://test/sso-login: Can't connect to test:80 (Bad hostname)
```

I can't change the href since it's our of my control. Is there a way to overcome this problem and make it take the full URL appending this href.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. You can modify the HTML that Mech is looking at just before you call `follow_link()`:

```
my $html = $mech->content;
$html =~ s[//test/sso-login][http://example.com/test/sso-login]isg;
$mech->update_html( $html );
```

See the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) for details. Search for "update_html" on that page.